# OutOfMemoryError in BitmapFactory.decodeFile()

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

When I pick image from gallery if image size bigger than 3 Mb android the OutOfMemoryError.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, options);
```

This text from logs. Please help me, becouse "deadline")

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:378)
        at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileActivity.java:104)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3402)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Comment: You have to scale your image at first.

Comment: Write your comment as answer and if this method work - I check your answer as rigth

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OutofMemory occurs when your app exceeds memory allocated in heap. The bitmap is too large to fit in memory ie heap. In such a case you run out of memory. You need to scale down the bitmap and then use the same.

[For that check this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

try this code may help you,

```
 public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
 try {
     //Decode image size
     BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

     //The new size we want to scale to
     final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
     final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
     //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
     int scale=1;
     while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
         scale*=2;

     //Decode with inSampleSize
     BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o2.inSampleSize=scale;
     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
 return null;
}
```

Comment: final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT; 
Is that necessary?

Answer (score 8):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
bmOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
bmOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
bmOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
Bitmap  mainBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bmOptions);
```